# Share inventory between my 3 stores (MSI disabled - Same Environment)

Tags: magento2, inventory, manage-stock

I have 3 stores that share the same stock for products. The stock is being handled by an external system, and in order for everything to work properly, they have been recommended to disable MSI (inventory) and activate Manage Stock. My Magento's version is 2.3.1

But if I do this, only the default store works, the other two stores don't work and show the following error:

```
Fout filteren sjabloon: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentodb.inventory_stock_sales_channel' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT inventory_stock_sales_channel.stock_id FROM inventory_stock_sales_channel WHERE (code = 'my_store_2' and type = "website")
```

Any ideas how I can keep this setting (MSI disabled) and be able to share the stock with the three stores?